# How can I scale my bitmap in Android based on the width and height pixels?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, resize, scale

I want to be able to scale my image based on the screen size. In a normal java applet I would do something like the following....

```
int windowWidth = 1280;
int windowHeight = 720;

Image image;

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    g.drawImage(image, x, y, windowWidth / 4, windowHeight / 16, null);
}
```

I've been searching for an answer for a while and everything I find seems to turn up some weird result. From what I read I might need  to do something with Resolution Independent Pixels but I'm not %100 sure.

The thing I am trying to avoid is having to create a whole new set of images and icons just for different screen densities. The method I showed above works for resizing desktop apps without a problem.

Edit:

This is what I have been using to draw an image in android.

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
Bitmap image;

Constuctor....()
{
image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.play);
}

public void render(Canvas c)
{
    c.drawBitmap(image, matrix, null);
}
```

Comment: ` Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()` or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331527/android-resize-a-large-bitmap-file-to-scaled-output-file

Answer (score 1):

Hi see thsi question I have posted [scale bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399089/how-to-scale-the-images-so-that-they-should-occupy-the-entire-screen)

If you are using canvas get the width and height of the canvas. or if you want to have it formal normal layouts then get the width and height by using

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
 getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
 dispWidth=metrics.widthPixels;
 dispheight=metrics.heightPixels;
```

and then scale our bitmap according to your requirement like this. In this I Have to have 8 bricks so I have taken the width by dividing with the Number of columns

```
      String strwidth=String.valueOf(((float)(bmp.getWidth())/NO_COLUMNS));
        if(strwidth.contains("."))
        {
            scalebit=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, (int)(Math.ceil(((float)bmp.getWidth())/NO_COLUMNS))*NO_COLUMNS, bmp.getHeight(), true);
        }
        else
        {
            scalebit=bmp;
        }
```